# Difference between 'not a' and 'not any'

Tags: grammar

are both **not a** and **not any** sound natural in the following examples?

1. Yesterday was mothers' day but I did not post **any photos** with my mother on social media. I think importance of my mother to my life cannot be described by just clicking pictures or posting them on social sites on mother's day.
2. Yesterday was mothers' day but I did not post **a photo** with my mother on social media. I think importance of my mother to my life cannot be described by just clicking a picture or posting it on social sites on mother's day.
3. Yesterday I visted a tiger reserve for the first time. After searching for hours I could not find **a tiger.**
4. Yesterday I visted a tiger reserve for the first time. After searching for hours I could not find **any tigers**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both "a" and "any" work, with very subtle differences in meaning.  "Any" suggests that we are talking about one out of many possible photos, or one out of many possible tigers.  "A" emphasizes singularity, that we are only talking about one tiger, or one photo, that does not exist, and makes no claim as to whether more than one is even being discussed.

Both end up in the same place: "not one" equals "zero".  The difference is merely in suggesting if more than one could have been an option in the first place.  "Any" implies there might have been more than one, while "a" doesn't broach the subject.